# Delete processed file apache-camel in a cluster

Tags: java, apache-camel, cluster-computing, idempotent

I use apache camel to process files received on a ftp channel. My application is deployed in a cluster (4 nodes), for this I use RedisIdempotentRepository to ensure that a single node processes the file. My problem is that I want to delete the file after processing, if I use `delete=true`, the node A that processed the file when it finishes and will delete the file, node B already deleted it because the node B will not go through the filter and therefore it will directly access the deletion.

I would like to know how to only allow node A to delete the file?

```
from("sftp://host:port/folder?delete=true)
 .idempotentConsumer(simple("${file:onlyname}"),
     RedisIdempotentRepository.redisIdempotentRepository(redisTemplate, "camel-repo"))
 .bean("orderTrackingFileProcessor");
```

Comment: What "filter"? When you say node B will nor go through the filter, what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean by "filter" is that the node B will check if the file's name exists in the redis database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I workaround this using [`pollEnrich`](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html):

**adding delete step at end of processing:**

```
.pollEnrich(remoteLocation + "?delete=true&fileName=${file:name}");
```

**Full Example Route:**

```
String remoteLocation = "sftp://host:port/folder";

from(remoteLocation)
 .idempotentConsumer(simple("${file:onlyname}"),
     RedisIdempotentRepository.redisIdempotentRepository(redisTemplate, "camel-repo"))
 .bean("orderTrackingFileProcessor")
 .pollEnrich(remoteLocation + "?delete=true&fileName=${file:name}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure the ftp endpoint to use the redis idempotent repository directly and not the idempotent consumer EIP in the route afterwards. That ensures only 1 ftp consumer is processing the same file.

If you have Camel in Action 2nd ed book its covered in the 2nd half of the transaction chapter.

Comment: idempotent is not adding any entry in repo when used in endpoint uri `file:///tmp/test1/request/?idempotent=true&idempotentRepository=%23sftpHazelcastIdempotentRepository&move=.done` - with EIP it works, but (node2) also deletes file (when `delete=true`)